# Draw Circle on top of image view

Tags: android, graphics

Currently on a view I have a ImageView and A custom class that draws a circle on the view. It will draw the circle on the view but it is hidden behind the image view. I know its there because when the radius is big enough I can see a small section that isn't behind the imageview. What code would bring it to the front?

EDIT: Found out that the above issue is not the problem. It seems that it is only drawing it on the portion that is reserved for the seekbar I have on the view?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_process);
     mDraw = new Draw(this);

    addContentView(mDraw, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    seekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    seekBar1.setMax(500);

     seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
             mDraw.setCords(500, 500, seekBar1.getProgress());
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             mDraw.setCords(500, 500, seekBar1.getProgress());              
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
             mDraw.setCords(500, 500, seekBar1.getProgress());              
        }

     });



}
```

Here is the Draw class:

```
  package org.DTS.boltsize;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class Draw extends View {
     private int x = 1;
     private int y = 1;
     private int r = 1;


    public Draw(Context context) {

            super(context);

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

public void setCords(int mx, int my, int mr ){
    x = mx;
    y = my;
    r = mr;
}


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.out.println("Drew :)");


            Paint paint = new Paint();

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, paint);
            super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    public void DrawCirlce(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int r){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }





}
```

Here is what it looks like. That red circle should cover the entire screen.
[image]

Comment: What are you drawing on?  a backgroung bitmap? another image view?

Comment: Drawing on the entire activity view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by converting source to bitmap, then drawing a circle on that bitmap and sending that final bitmap to the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw to a seperate bitmap that you have in a different imageView in the same space as your curent bitmap possibly in a FrameLayout.  You can then use .bringToFront to decide the z order.